# Average number of rows per variable in SAS

Tags: sas, proc

I have the following dataset :

```
    data test;
    input business_ID $;
    datalines;
   'busi1'
   'busi1'
   'busi1'
   'busi2'
   'busi3'
   'busi3'
   ;
    run;

proc freq data = test ;
        table business_ID;
run;
```

I  would like the average nummber of lines per business, that is count the total number of observations and divide it by the number of distinct businesses.
In my example : 6 observations, 3 businesses -> 6/2=3 lines per business.

I was thinking about using a `proc freq` or a `proc mean` step but so far I got only the number of lines (~freq) per business and do not know how to get to my goal.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use PROC FREQ to get the counts and then run PROC MEANS on the output.

```
proc freq data=test ;
  tables business_id / noprint out=counts ;
run;
proc means data=counts;
  var count;
run;
```

[image]

Or you could count them directly with PROC SQL code.

```
proc sql ;
  select count(*)/count(distinct business_id) as mean_count
  from test
  ;
quit;
```

[image]